# What happen if I try to restore a bigger backup in a different phone?

Tags: backup, 8.1-update-1, micro-sd

I have a **Lumia 920 32GB** and just bought a **Lumia 830 16GB** internal memory but I can increase up to 128GB with an SD card.

My question is: When I start the setup of the new phone it will start to download almost 32GB apps but I will have just the half. It will prompt me what to do or it will be like crazy download everything it can until fill the entire memory?

Comment: Haven't tested this so I'm not going to give it as an answer, but based on several similar things I've done, I'd say it would download as much as it could, then tell you that you are out of storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would begin to download all of yours apps that were in backup, but then as soon as you don't have any space for anymore of the other apps, it will stop and warn you about low storage. It pauses all downloads and you would have to go into the store and retry the apps you want downloaded.

Comment: It happened to you?

Comment: I've had to restore my phone multiple times with different sized microSD cards, so yes, I've experienced this problem before.